# agora api intergration for chat , audio and video call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, agora

i am using video call UI kit I want to send request users to receive video call how can I do this agora?

i have make video call functionality using agora UI kit I can join call but i want to make request to users to receive the video call

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.